# Setting style on parent SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have the following HTML. In this case it has a button to toggle the error message, but in real life this will be dynamic

```
<md-card>
  <md-card-content layout-padding>
    <div class="subtitle"><span translate="allocation"></span></div>
    <div><md-button ng-click="test = !test">Testing</md-button></div>
    <div class="infoMessages" ng-show="test">
      Error
    </div>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>

<md-card>
  <md-card-content layout-padding>
    <div class="subtitle"><span translate="allocation"></span></div>
    <div><md-button ng-click="test = !test">Testing</md-button></div>
    <div class="infoMessages" ng-show="test">
      Error
    </div>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

now I'm trying to set the border color of the md-card to red when the Error is visible, this is equal to the `.infoMessages` class being visible inside the `md-card`.

I tried some scss configurations but I can't seem to select my parent. This is close I think, but I'm not sure.

```
md-card {
  md-card-content + .infoMessages & {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

Code pen for testing: https://codepen.io/cskiwi/pen/jYxyqy

I started wondering if it is even possible, any suggestions?
Anyway already thanks for reading!

Greetings Glenn

Comment: Thats not possible with css, how will you turn visible the `.infoMessages`? To do this you'r going to need javascript

Comment: Or just change the structure, place the `.infoMessages` outside the `md-card-content`, maybe inside a new tag

Comment: or maybe use ng-class="{'error': test1 === true}" on md-card-content and apply your style to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply style to parent selector. It's not existing in css, nor sass.

But you can use ng-class on md-card-content :

```
<md-card-content layout-padding ng-class="{'error': test1 == true}">
```

And then apply style like this :

```
md-card-content {
    &.error {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
}
```

Fork of your codepen : https://codepen.io/Alvan/pen/RxyKMP

By the way, i needed to set `display:block;` on **md-card-content** because this element has no base style at all.

Oh sorry, you were talking about md-card. Mh. Sorry, my mistake, but this will work the same for md-card.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to set styles on a parent based on child or later sibling selectors in CSS. Selectors only work in two basic ways, by selecing some sibling further down the HTML document or some nested child node. Just as you cant set styles on a parent you can not set styles on a previous sibling.

In your example the computed style you have here is `md-card-content + .infoMessages md-card` which would make `md-card` a child of `.infoMessages`

You could change the color by using javascript to determine if the error is visible and then find the closest `md-card` parent or you could add an `error` class to the `md-card` and then you could change the color and visibility at the same time.